# Unix: How to merge two directories

Tags: unix, shell, file-management

Say I have two folders with various content, `foo` and `bar`. How can I merge `bar` into `foo` so that:

- Files in `foo` that are not in `bar` are untouched.
- Files in `bar` that are not in `foo` are now in `foo`.
- Files in `foo` that are also in `bar` have been replaced by the files from `bar`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If I'm reading your requirements correctly, there's no files that go from `foo` to `bar`. It looks like you can just copy the contents of `bar` to `foo`, letting it overwrite files as necessary (its default behavior).

```
$ cp -R /path/to/bar/* /path/to/foo
```

Comment: Yeah, what I was uncertain about was the recursiveness and how to not end up with just having bar inside foo as foo/bar. But this seems to be what I want :)

Comment: Right, if you just did `cp -R /path/to/bar /path/to/foo` it would create a directory `bar` inside `foo`. Subtle point.

Comment: Note: it will omit hidden files/directories in `bar` (i.e. with names starting with a dot – `.`) because of how shell globbing works.

Answer (score 12):

I had a very similar need: merge `bar` into `foo` but files which are in `bar` **should not** overwrite matching files in `foo`.  In this case:

```
$ cp -R -n /path/to/bar/* /path/to/foo/
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

`$ cp -r`**`-u`**`-v /path/to/foo/* /path/to/bar/`

From `man cp`
 ***-u, --update***
              copy only when the SOURCE file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing
***-R, -r, --recursive*** copy directories recursively

Comment: Two people have already suggested the cp command and so your answer seems superfluous. Taking a few minutes to explain how the arguments you've selected do a better job than the other suggestions will help make your answer more helpful.

Comment: The -u flag updates only if the file in the source is newer that the one in the destination. See : `man cp`    -> -u, --update :  copy only when the SOURCE file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing

Comment: Add that information to the question (use Edit right below your post) so that people can see that helpful information in the answer itself.