# Merging two directory trees with same structure, but different contents in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, rsync, cp

I have two directories with the following structure:

```
A
|_0
|_1
|_2

B
|_0
|_1
|_2
```

each 0,1,2 directory contains unique contents. I want all of the contents to simply exist as:

```
A
|_0
|_1
|_2
```

Is there a one liner for this? This is simplified, as the directory structure is about 4 layers deep with 16 directories per level...so it's huge.

Comment: Is this a temporary merge, or permanent?   If temporary, you could use something like unionfs perhaps?

Comment: By "unique contents" do you mean all the files in A have different names than in B? If so, a simple recursive copy will suffice, as in: http://superuser.com/questions/242638/unix-how-to-merge-two-directories/242645#242645

Comment: Unfortunately I just realized that the files may have the same names, but they certainly have different contents.

Answer (score 0):

Given enough space, I would copy A to C, then B to C.

```
mkdir C
cp -rp A/* C
cp -rp B/* C
```

Comment: Hmmm, the files may have the same name, and If I had fileA and fileA I'd like to have both (perhaps, fileA and fileA.1 or something)